# what is meant by extension and binary file of a library?

Tags: php, webserver, python-imaging-library, imagick

This is more of a general question but for reference, I read statements like: "Most of the shared hosting providers do not compile imagick extension with PHP, but imagick binaries will be available". I don't know what is meant by "imagick extension" and "imagick binaries"? To me, any non-txt file is a binary. Also, when we install a library like "imagick", are both these kinds of version installed? And what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Imagick extension" is the optional component of PHP that adds Imagick-related functions to the language.

"binaries" means programs that are compiled to machine code, as opposed to source code or scripts.

So they're saying that you won't be able to use the built-in Imagic functions in PHP, but you could execute the external programs using methods like `shell_exec()`.

Comment: okay! Thanks! do you know any other extensions which are common and I can relate to? Also, do you mean they provide extra functions over the ones provided by the source code of the library?

Comment: Other common extensions are `mysqli` and `PDO` for using databases.

Comment: If you call `phpinfo()` you'll see all the extensions that are enabled in your PHP configuration.

Comment: _"...do you mean they provide extra functions over the ones provided by the source code of the library?"_ No, they provide the same functionality as the imagick stand-alone command line tool, but as a native PHP functions. The primary advantage is that you don't need to rely on techniques that can introduce remote code execution vulnerabilities. For that reason, you may also find that PHP functions like `exec()`, `shell_exec()` and `popen()` are not allowed by your host. Given that, and how dirt cheap a full root VPS is nowadays, I'd recommend not even bothering with a shared hosting provider.